# How to paste file location in QTP

Tags: vbscript

There is one test case in QTP to copy one file path from my c drive to the application. The location of the destination area is

```
Browser("Modify").Page("Modify").ActiveX("Java Plug-in 11.161.2").WinObject("SunAwtCanvas")
```

and first I need to identify the coordinate of this area. I have tried using `getroproperty("X")` but it didn't work out.

Code to copy-paste the file

```
Set WshShell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell") WshShell.SendKeys "^c"
Browser("Modify").Page("Modify").ActiveX("Java Plug-in 11.161.2").WinObject("SunAwtCanvas").Click 1,1 
Browser("Modify").Page("Modify").ActiveX("Java Plug-in 11.161.2").WinObject("SunAwtCanvas").highlight 
Browser("Modify").Page("Modify").ActiveX("Java Plug-in 11.161.2").WinObject("SunAwtCanvas").Click WshShell.SendKeys "^v"
```

Can anyone tell me how to locate this destination area so that I can paste my file name there? Note: it's not a text-area.

Comment: So are you trying to do drag and drop or you just need to get the file path? In case you just need filepath, why not use FSO?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I need to copy the  file and paste tin the attached area 
Code:Set WshShell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

 WshShell.SendKeys "^c"
 Browser("Modify").Page("Modify").ActiveX("Java Plug-in 11.161.2").WinObject("SunAwtCanvas").Click 1,1

 Browser("Modify").Page("Modify").ActiveX("Java Plug-in 11.161.2").WinObject("SunAwtCanvas").highlight
Browser("Modify").Page("Modify").ActiveX("Java Plug-in 11.161.2").WinObject("SunAwtCanvas").Click 
 WshShell.SendKeys "^v"
But before pasting its unable to click on the desired area ..problem is i cant identify the coordinates.